# Reference 'seg_type' not supported (reference to group function)

Tags: mysql

i wrote a sql and it told me this exception,how could i solve this problem

```
SELECT 
b.project_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(b.segment_type ORDER BY b.segment_type SEPARATOR ',' )  AS seg_type
FROM t_project_bid_announce_draft b  
LEFT JOIN t_project_segment t ON t.project_id = b.project_id
WHERE (b.review_status = 2 OR  b.review_status = 3)
AND b.deleted = 0
AND seg_type != t.segment_type
GROUP BY b.project_id
```

please help me,thanks a lot.

update

i use the sql without

```
AND seg_type != t.segment_type
```

like

```
SELECT b.project_id,GROUP_CONCAT(b.segment_type ORDER BY b.segment_type SEPARATOR ',' )  
AS seg_type,t.segment_type 
FROM t_project_bid_announce_draft b  
LEFT JOIN t_project_segment t ON t.project_id = b.project_id
WHERE (b.review_status = 2 OR  b.review_status = 3)
AND b.deleted = 0
GROUP BY b.project_id
```

and than i got this [RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnPrw.jpg)

i want compare

```
seg_type
```

and

```
t.segment_type
```

Comment: `WHERE` gets executed *before* the grouping, so you cannot use the result of `GROUP_CONCAT` inside the `WHERE` clause. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to compare the result of this    GROUP_CONCAT and    t.segment_type

Comment: Can you share some sample data along with expected result?

Comment: i update my question...my english is not good....that is too difficult to describe my question on StackOverflow... OMG